# Highlight cells based on the value of cells in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have this problem as noted below:

Column A = Part number

Column B = Quantity

Column C = Part number

Column D = Quantity

Using conditional formatting, I would like to highlight if the combination of Part number and Quantity in Column A and B is different to the combination of Part number and Quantity in Column C and D.

Eg:

```
     Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D  
 1   1111     2      1112     5
 2   1112     3      1111     2
 3   1131     5      1112     5
 4   1122     3      1131     2
```

To do this, I'd like to set up a couple of 'helper' columns (say E & F) by concatenating Column A & B, C & D.

So essentially, I'd like to take the information from the helper columns E & F, but use conditional formatting to highlight the cell in column B and D.

From the example above, cell B3 and D4 would be highlighted.

Is this possible, and if not, is there are simple alternative? (I don't mind using a macro if need be).

Comment: Perfect approach! Conditional format for `B1:B4` would be `=B1<>E1` and for `C1:C4` would be `=C1<>F1`. Use Conditional format based on formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use COUNTIFS

For B1:B4

```
=COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$4,A1,$D$1:$D$4,"<>"&B1)
```

and for D1:D4

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,C1,$B$1:$B$4,"<>"&D1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you even want to skip the helper columns, you could  format A1 with `=$A1&$B1<>$C1&$D1` and copy the format to any cells in you want to be highlighted (even to your helper columns).